# 文字列を逆にしてリストに格納するコードについて

Tags: python

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
for c in "iterable":
    list1.append(c)
while len(list1)>0:
    j=-1#これと
    d=list1.pop(j)
    j+=1#これは別にいらない。
    list2.append(d)
print(list2)
```

というコードによって文字列を逆順にしました。
①もう少し短く書けないでしょうか？

本当は、whileループを使わずに、forループのみを用いて同じことをしたかったのですが、
appendに変数`c`のインデックスを指定した文字を入れるにはどうすればよいかわかりませんでした。
②forループのみでappendメソッドを用いて文字列を最後から入れていくコードは書けるのでしょうか？
**（※②の質問に追記）**
この質問では、`for`と`append`、インデックスの指定方法（別途必要であれば）の３つの要素から成るコードで冒頭のコードを書き換えることができないかという旨で質問しました。
なので、コメントに書いてくださったようにlen関数を使うことでインデックスを指定することができるのであればlen関数が含まれているか否かは問いません。

以上２つが疑問点です。

Comment: 「appendメソッドを用いて」以外に何か縛りはあるのでしょうか?例えば`reversed`は使っても良いのかどうかですが。

Comment: ①の疑問点については、縛りはありませんが、②については、appendのみでうまくいくのか知りたいです。

Comment: 「appendのみ」と言うことですが、例えば`for`の中に出てくる式で`len`を使うことさえダメなのでしょうか?

Comment: 確かに、ご指摘の通り②の質問は具体性に乏しいですね。

Comment: 少し質問内容を変更いたしますので、再度ご覧いただけると幸いです。

Comment: なかなか難しいですが、「何かを逆順にするのに`reversed`のような一発お手軽メソッドを使っちゃダメ」と「結果のリストは値を`append`で詰め込んでいくことで作成する」あたりを明示しておけば良いように思います。私はPythonistじゃないんで、①にうまく答えられないんでパスしますが、それほど時間をおかず回答が集まるかと思います。

Comment: append にこだわりがなければ insert メソッドでも良いかと思いますが(`list1.insert(0, c)`)

Answer (score 1):

単に文字列の後ろから文字をなめていくというだけなら、下のようにできます。[OOPer さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/46840/19110)と同じく、文字列の最後の文字から順番にインデックス指定して詰めています。

```
s = "string"
l = []
for i in range(len(s)):
  l.append(s[len(s) - i - 1])
```

また、今回の要件に合っているか微妙ですが、slice を使ってリストを部分的に取り出せることと、slice には開始点、終了点、step 数を指定できること、およびそれらには負の値を指定できることを使うと、次のように書くこともできます。

```
s = list("string")
l = s[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

①の「もう少し短く書けないでしょうか？」についてはパスさせてもらって、②だけですが、こんなのではどうですかと言うのを。

```
str = "string"
list = []
for i in range(len(str)-1,-1,-1):
    list.append(str[i])
```

「インデックスの指定方法」と言う追記がありましたので、文字列のインデックスを指定して、文字を取り出すのはありと解釈しました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: insertメソッドを使うと確かに簡単ですね・・・使い慣れてなくてすぐに出てこないです。まだまだ勉強ですね。。

Comment: OOPerさんの手法と似た考え方で、リストのsliceで負のstepを指定できることを使えば `list2 = list1[::-1]` と書けますが、今回の要件にあっているか微妙ですね。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、ここはPythonのコードギャラリーを作るためのサイトではないとはいえ、質問中の要件に完全には合わなくても、「同じ結果を得られるPythonコード」ですし、回答としてご紹介いただく価値のある内容に思いますが。

Comment: @OOPer さん、ご提案ありがとうございます。投稿してみました。

Answer (score 0):

こんなのはいかがでしょうか?
行数を少なくすることはできますし、わかりやすいと思います。

```
l = list("Hello")
l.reverse()

print(l)
```